# Sterlizing rags, sponges and scrubbers in a microwave?

Tags: cleaning, technology, kitchen

Recently I've gotten worried about overuse of cleaning rags / sponges / scouring pads / scrubbers in my kitchen (let's call them "scrubbers" for short), and whether I should perhaps replace them more often than I do. Then I got to thinking - maybe I could just sterilize them thoroughly to increase their longevity?

My questions are:

- Is this known to be effective?
- Are there health risks to this procedure (e.g. material detaching from the sponge/scrubber and going into my food)?
- How long and with what amount of power should I nuke my scrubber?
- Is there there some preparation work I need to do?

Comment: This should be asked in the context of our [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) site (assuming it hasn't already) where they investigate the truth or effectiveness of notable claims. Exploring whether these techniques work or disproving them is not within the topic for this site --  https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1296/80. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: The skeptics site is not a place to discuss how to best apply what seems to be a sound method. I would claim that using your microwave for sterilization is a hack indeed: It's an "uncommon solutions to a common problem" and an "unusual way of using an everyday object to make life easier".

Comment: I agree that the 'microwave for sterilization is a hack indeed'; a novel alternative to pouring boiling water over your cleaning rags as my great grandmother and following generations used to do. However you provided the hack in the question and asked if (and how) it is going to work, what is an approach that has been decided by votes not to work for this site. If you don't agree with this policy, follow the link to meta provided by  @RobertCartaino read the question and answers and cast your own votes.

Answer (score 2):

This article:

[Researchers: Microwave oven can sterilize sponges, scrub pads](http://news.ufl.edu/archive/2007/01/researchers-microwave-oven-can-sterilize-sponges-scrub-pads.html)

Suggests the following:

- Before doing this, make sure the scrubber has no metal content
- Douse your scrubber fully in water *<- really?*
- 2 min suffice for 99% of bacteria/pathogens <- *but at what power?*
- 4 min are required for rare super-resistant spores <- *but at what power?*
- If you cook and use your scrubber every day, sterilize it every other day

but I would very much like to hear other people's experience and suggestions. Also, the article did not say what power output setting should be used.

Comment: Careful. Microwaves (reportedly) can sterilize items by heating them, not through the process of irradiation.  Irradiating is where ionizing radiation is used to denature any bacteria and other pathogens. Microwaves to not emit any ionizing radiation, so calling any items you place in there "irradiated" is simply not correct.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Edited to avoid the argument, but you're wrong, in these sense that "irradiating" = "exposing to radiation", and [A microwave oven is a kitchen appliance that heats and cooks food by exposing it to electromagnetic radiation in the microwave frequency range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven).

Comment: I'm curious about the size of sponges they used: when i microwave my sponge in a bowl of water for 1 minute it reaches boiling temperature, thus effectively killing off most lifeforms within.

Comment: @Ivana: Some micro-organisms are resistant to short exposures to heat.

Comment: FWIW, I have read in various generic sources that when otherwise not stated, 1000 watts is assumed for MW oven power.

Comment: FWIW, I had no success with using the microwave. I had better success with soaking in weak concentration of household liquid chlorine bleach.

Comment: @Stan: My microwave doesn't even have that setting...

Comment: @Stan: How can you tell you had no success with the microwave?

Comment: Check the inside of the oven's door, on the serial number plate on the back of the oven, or in the owner's manual or the manufacturer's website for the wattage. An approximate conversion for oven Power (watts) is equal to Amps. X Voltage (110 - 115 in North America).

Comment: When the sponge/scrubber has an odour of mildew or mould after the treatment, it's a FAIL.

Comment: @Stan: I wonder, though... wouldn't we get this odour if the bacteria die, as well?

Comment: To estimate wattage you can do a "Time-to-Boil Test:"
Measure 1 cup water in a 2-cup glass measure. Add ice cubes; stir until water is ice cold. Discard ice cubes and pour out any water more than 1 cup. Set microwave on high 4 minutes. Watch the water through the window to see when it boils. If water boils:
in less than 2 minutes = very high wattage oven (1000 watts or more).
in 2½ minutes = high wattage oven (800 watts or more).
in 3 minutes = average wattage oven (650 - 700 watts or more).
in 3 - 4 minutes = slow oven (300 to 500 watts).